# Trying to fetch data in a webpage with Google ImportXML

Tags: import, fetch

I am trying to fetch the value 44.244815 from this code's web site using Google Sheet but I can't seams to make it work.  Anyone would know how to fetch this data and import it?

[Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJtCm.png)

Comment: It is impossible to answer without the url. The site could be built by javascript, and if this is the case you will not be able to use the native functions, and probably not any script !

Comment: web site is https://solo-etc.2miners.com/

Comment: I can't find this value (44.244815) ... Do you mean price ETC?

Comment: Yes correct the total ETC Paid now at 53.702555

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=index(importxml(url,"//div[@class='col-xs-6']//h4"),9,1)
```

or

```
=index(importxml(A1,"//h4"),13,1)
```